# Automate Unloading redshift data ,other files from drives,web api to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, loading

I have some data to be ingested from redshift to snowflake.currently I use unload command to get it to s3 bucket and then load it to snowflake for redshift and aws cp for other files.
I am looking for someway to automate this unloading .Looking for suggestions .I also have a use case to load the delta of these data so will have to run it on a schedule.
Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**
DataPipeline is deprecated:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/migration.html

You could use a lambda if you are confident that the execution time will be less than 15 minutes
Otherwise you could use a [data pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/details/).
You can schedule ec2 instances to execute your process. You could write a bash script that to do what you require. Unload data from redshift etc. Or you could use an existing template and modify it visually in the "architect" tool in the AWS console

**Create a new pipeline using a template (Full copy of RDS MySql to S3)**

[image]

**Configure the pipeline and press Edit in architect**

[image]

**You will see a graph similar to the one below.
You can easily adjust it to use Redshift instead of RDS (As it's displayed in the screenshot)**

[image]

Comment: Thank You.Some queries took 45 mins to unload .I went through data pipeline.Can this be used for S3 to redshift

Comment: Pls see my updated answer. I hope it helps